# Link one express js application to another

Tags: node.js, express

I have two Express JS application and I want to add a route for one inside the other so when this link is requested it goes to the sub-application. Is that possible??

Example:

The main application is accessed through the link www.linktoapp.com and it is written in Express js.

Now I have developed another Express js application and I want to access it through the link www.linktoapp.com/secondapp

My question is can I add this route (/sceondapp) in the main application so I can access it like I said?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more information on what exactly you're trying to do and what your case is.

Comment: Thanx @majidarif I have edited the question and added an example.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing! What I understand from your question:

You have two expressjs application running. Two application can't run on same port. Two application can however run on two different ports. See example below.

```
var express = require("express");
var app1 = express(); //created the first app
var app2 = express(); //created the second app
app1.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.send("<html><body><a href='/sec'>go second app</a></body></html>");
    // created a link to app2
});

app1.get("/sec",function(req,res){ // redirection to second app
    res.redirect("http://localhost:3001/");
})
app2.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.send("welcome to second app");
});


app2.listen(3001,function(){ //  app2 is listening on port 3001
    console.log("app two is listening on 30001 ")
});
app1.listen(3000,function(){ // app2 is listening on 3000
    console.log("app1 is listening on 3000");
});
```

Comment: The problem is the two applications are separately developed but now I need to add the one to the other.

Comment: so whats the problem run first app on one port and run second app on different port and link those apps using absolute link. But remember you can't use this in production unless your second app is used as a proxy. because two app cant listen on same port i.e 80

Comment: can I use it like how I use routes? 
i.e.
`app2=require('./app');
app1.use('/secondapp', app2);`

Comment: you have mentioned two applications are separately developed so app 1 must have its own routs and app2 must have its own. But in certain cases we need to redirect users form app1 two app2 . So in those cases we need to redirect users from app1 routs to app2.

Answer (score 0):

You could always have two separate express processes running on 2 ports and then reverse proxy  the requests.

https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to create an Express sub-app.  Express sub-apps share routes, views, sessions, etc with the main app.

For example, let's say you want one node app, s_app.js, to be a sub-app of another, p_app.js.

**s_app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = module.express = express();

// set routes for userjs
app.get('/path_1', function(req, res){
  // display path_1
});
```

**p_app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var s_app = require('s_app');  // mount s_app.js
app.use(s_app);

// now p_app and s_app share routes, views, sessions, etc
```

If you want more detail, take a look at a tutorial I wrote on [how to build node.js sub-apps](http://handyjs.org/article/your-guide-to-the-dark-arts-of-nodejs-sub-apps)